# UITableViewCell setSelected method not getting called

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am on iOS7 and have a UITableViewCell subclass for my UITableView with static cells. I am overriding the setSelected method in the implementation.

For some reason, the method only gets called when the table loads but doesn't get called when the cell is actually tapped and selected.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get it to work?

```
@implementation StudentMenuMultipleOptionsTableViewCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if (selected) {
        UIView *view = [UIView new];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.542 green:0.788 blue:0.060 alpha:1.000];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = view;
    }
    else {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[BlackBackgroundSelectedButton class]]) {
                BlackBackgroundSelectedButton *button = (BlackBackgroundSelectedButton *)view;
                button.selected = NO;
                [button setWhite];
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Edited the question with code

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the setSelected method. The method that needs to be used for the newer iOS versions is:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: That may work as a fix in your situation but your statement isn't true - setSelected() has animated and non-animated function versions and the one you refer to above calls the non-animated version to do the work ... it just adds a layer of animation around the call. I am debugging a similar problem that could be related - my setSelected function gets called but always with a value of NO ... which makes no sense.

Comment: I am pretty sure that setSelected is an internal method and isn't meant to be overridden. This looks like the designated method for overriding. Apple does this for other UIElements like UIButton as well. Do a UIButtonInstance.titleLabel.text = @"XYZZ" and you will see that the button behaves erratically. You will have to use the [UIButtonInstance setTitle:@"xyzz" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal] for it to behave like it should.

Comment: setSelected() is a public method like any other, override it's behaviour where required - that's what Object Orientation and Polymorphism is all about, a means for customising behaviour by subclassing objects. The tricky bit is finding the right place to override behaviour in the appropriate fashion.

Comment: Exactly. I never said that you won't be able to override the "setSelected" method, just that you aren't supposed to for this particular case. You will see in the developer documentation that this is an undocumented API and the "selected" property is meant to be only read to check that current selected status of the cell.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree - it is a documented API call/property ... but no doubt I will find out in a few weeks from our Appstore review.